# Using Javascript to change CSS for URL

Tags: javascript, css

I have a url in my HTML as seen below.  I have made the url inactive

```
<a style="pointer-events: none; color: rgb(44, 89, 159);" href="https://www.google.com/" id="successfactors">Link</a>
```

I am trying to reactivate the link via Javascript.  I tried the code below, but when I did the page didn't load correctly.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or a better way to make a link inactive/active?

```
document.getElementById('successfactors').style.pointer-events = 'auto';
```

Comment: `-` is not valid in dot notation, use bracket notation: `.style['pointer-events'] = '...'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
document.getElementById('successfactors').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

Styles use camel case, as identifiers can't contain hyphens.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you use CSS and javascript in a manner which clearly distinguishes the two.

Define your CSS styles:

```
.inactive
{
   pointer-events: none;
   color: rgb(44, 89, 159);
}

.active
{
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Toggle the CSS class of the elements with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("successfactors").className = "inactive";
```

It's neater and tidier, and I promise you widely-used inline styles eventually cause headaches.